# How do I get my Java Program to correctly display "Fn" and accept "n" from the Fibonacci sequence formula provided?

Tags: java, fibonacci

Here's what I have so far, but I am unsure where to go from here. This is the formula I am supposed to use

[image: 1] 
[image: 2]

Comment: question unclear

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please take time to review the [tour] and [ask]. Try to include a [mcve] directly in your question, do not post an image of code.

Comment: So you want to know how to input `N`?

Comment: Have you not learned how to take user input?

Answer (score 0):

```
int n;
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in)
n = scan.nextInt();
```

This code waits until you enter something and press enter, keeps on going and stores your value in the n-variable;